# Query over results of 'sp_lock' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-locking

Theres is a built-in stored procedure in SQL Server called [sp_lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-lock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).
It will return a table which contains information about current locks in database  server. It will return several columns including `dbid` which is id of each database. I want to query only one specific database id, but I don't know how to execute a query over returned result of `sp_lock`.

I want to know how to query over results of `sp_lock`?

Comment: See the "Important" note in the documentation you link, you should be querying `sys.dm_tran_locks` not using this deprecated proc (Which `sp_helptext 'sp_lock'` indicates dates back to 1996)

Answer (score 1):

See the "Important" note in the documentation you link, you should be querying sys.dm_tran_locks not using this deprecated proc (Which sp_helptext 'sp_lock' indicates dates back to 1996), eg this will return locks in the current database:

```
select *
from sys.dm_tran_locks
where resource_database_id = db_id()
```

Comment: I already had viewed result of `sys.dm_tran_locks` however it was not as readable as `sp_lock` output. Personally, brief and readable results of `sp_lock` helped to me resolve issues in my database while. This might be because I'm not a DBA and I'm a developer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However `sp_lock` have a column named `type` which shows what resources is locked (Database, Table, Page, Row and etc.). How can we differntiate between page locks and table locks in ` sys.dm_tran_locks` ? I could not understand how to diffrentiate between resource types in output of [sys.dm_tran_locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-locks-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) by interpreting `resource_associated_entity_id`?

Comment: It’s resource_type.

Comment: I know it is resource type. I want to know how the tables are differentiated from pages according the type. Since the type is not explicitly shows which resource are tables and which of them of page and etc.